# App crashed on ios 6

Tags: ios, crash, jasidepanels

we build an app and used JASidePanelController in it. It is working fine on iOS 7 but in iOS6, at loading time, app crashes. There is no specific reason displayed in log and control goes to "**main.m**"
Can any one please help me as i can not understand whats going on here ...
 Here is the log:

```
GuardMalloc[MCPDemo-1133]: recording malloc stacks to disk using standard recorder
GuardMalloc[MCPDemo-1133]: Allocations will be placed on 16 byte boundaries.
GuardMalloc[MCPDemo-1133]:  - Some buffer overruns may not be noticed.
GuardMalloc[MCPDemo-1133]:  - Applications using vector instructions (e.g., SSE) should work.
GuardMalloc[MCPDemo-1133]: version 27
DemoApp(1133,0x34ce1a8) malloc: stack logs being written into /tmp/stack-logs.1133.8e0b000.MCPDemo.RMUUtx.index
dladdr(0x344ea6d, 0xbfffca48)
_dyld_register_func_for_add_image(0x3264cf2)
_dyld_register_func_for_remove_image(0x3264d52)
2014-03-02 20:13:59.756 DemoApp[1133:907] Keyboard Manager enabled
2014-03-02 20:14:00.858 DemoApp[1133:907] serveraddress:8888/servername/
```

Comment: can you check :
https://github.com/gotosleep/JASidePanels/pull/164

Answer (score 0):

You'll be able to see more useful output from the debug console if you add an "All Exceptions" breakpoint. This will typically take you directly to the line of code that is causing the issue instead of dropping you into main.m.

Instructions can be found at http://blog.manbolo.com/2012/01/23/xcode-tips-1-break-on-exceptions

Comment: I have added "All Exceptions" breakpoint, But still there is no useful log and is returning to main.